# Apache Kafka - iOS consumer

Tags: ios, apache-kafka, publish-subscribe, websub

Has anyone implemented iOS devices as a consumer of kafka? Is there any client libraries in Obj-C or Swift that could subscribe to Kafka topics?

Comment: Did you find anything available?

Comment: I was not able to find anything that is supported natively.

Comment: [swift kafka](https://github.com/kellanburket/franz/) i found this it works fine

Answer (score 2):

I don't think consuming Kafka streams directly on a mobile device is the right way to go, unless you are doing some research kind of work. The ideal solution would be to have a REST API (a small web service) that can talk directly to Kafka. You can then poll API endpoints to retrieve messages from Kafka.

For instance, you can write a web service using Python [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) framework integrated with [`kafka-python`](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python) as a solution.